# Error while trying to upload CSV file from S3 to DynamoDB using AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to upload CSV files from S3 to Amazon DynamoDB using AWS Lambda. I am using Python 2.7. The file has just 2 columns: Name and ID. The code is as follows:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def csv_reader(event, context):

    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)

    rows = obj['Body'].read().split('\n')

    table = dynamodb.Table('test_table')

    with table.batch_writer() as batch:
        for row in rows:
            batch.put_item(Item={

                'Name':row.split(',')[0],
                'ID':row.split(',')[1]
            })
```

I am getting this error:

```
An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation: Requested resource not found: ResourceNotFoundException
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 24, in csv_reader
'ID':row.split(',')[1]
File "/var/runtime/boto3/dynamodb/table.py", line 156, in __exit__
self._flush()
File "/var/runtime/boto3/dynamodb/table.py", line 137, in _flush
RequestItems={self._table_name: items_to_send})
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation: Requested resource not found
```

If I try uploading any other file I still face the same error. Can anyone suggest what I should do?

Comment: Seems like your table name is wrong. Make sure 'test_table' exist

Comment: While you do what @SumeetP suggested. Try checking data-type for `obj['Body'].read()` . If its `bytes` convert to `str` then use `split`